# Oganization of Folders in XCode

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, resourcebundle, nsbundle

I'm using physical folders to organise my files in XCode, as I have multiple files with the same name. Eg: /skin1/navbar.jpg and /skin2/navbar.jpg.

Every time I add a new file, I can't drag it into the folder, it seems like once I ad the folder as a group in XCode, it gets locked somehow and I can't change it. When I try to initialize a UIImage with this method, it turns out to be `nil`.

Using this image as an example:
[image: The path to the file]

[image: The full tree]

To create a UIImage I'm using this:

```
    NSString *skinBasePath = [AppearanceUtils skinBasePath]; // Returns /Users/echilon/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/E6C7ECF4-B36A-4092-97BC-CDE2D0A526C2/ReadMeAStory.app/ReadMeAStory/images/skin/wood/
    NSString *bgImagePath = [skinBasePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"button_181_43.png"],
             *bgImagePathPressed = [skinBasePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"button_181_43_pressed.png"];
    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:bgImagePath]
```

Everything looks fine in the debugger until I actually create the image, which comes back as null.

The full path to the image in the debugger is `/Users/echilon/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/E6C7ECF4-B36A-4092-97BC-CDE2D0A526C2/ReadMeAStory.app/ReadMeAStory/images/skin/wood/button_181_43.png`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"images" is just a Group and not a Folder, so `.../ReadMeAStory.app/ReadMeAStory/images/` don't exist. 
What are you doing in `[AppearanceUtils skinBasePath]`?

Maybe this will help: 
`NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button_181_43" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"skin/wood"];`